# Employer page shows benefits on right with text misaligned on mobile Safari

Tags: bug, status-declined, jobs, mobile-safari

Navigate to a company's profile page in mobile Safari. Scroll down to the benefits section.

Example link to view on mobile Safari: [Stack Exchange's Company Page](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/company/stack-exchange#benefits)

If there are long phrases on the right side items, the alignment is rendered as right-aligned.

**Using Safari on an iPhone with IOS 8.1.2** - Dec 22 2014

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

**Using Safari on an iPhone with IOS 8.1.1**

[image: Stack Exchange benefits]

[image: Campaign Monitor benefits]

Comment: Can you please confirm it's not happening anymore?

Comment: @shadow Updated with some recent screenshots showing misalingment in iOS 8.1.2

Answer (score 2):

This issue originates from a Mobile Safari bug.

The styles are misinterpreted in an inconsistent manner, and inspection in Mobile Safari shows incoherences, hence there is no proposed fix at this time.

Comment: Hey, can you still reproduce now with iOS 8.1.2? OP and my see the issue, but Hynes doesn't.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes, I can still repro it intermittently

Comment: Weird. So you sure it's internal Safari bug, and not something in the code?

Comment: Starting The safari remote debugger fixes the layout, and the inspector in this debugger shows inconsistent info (calculated style doesn't match the loaded styles). Also, the bug only appears in safari and is intermittent. With all these elements, I think it's safe to assume it'a a bug in safari

Comment: Fair enough. On a hunch, I [did this check](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fcareers.stackoverflow.com%2Fcompany%2Fstack-exchange&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en) and there appears to be many errors and warnings... is this normal? Maybe Safari isn't as forgiving as other browsers? (Personally I don't really use this validator)

Comment: I fixed some of the css rules to be w3c compliant, although I couldn't fix *all* of them (there are external css, IE hacks, ...) Unfortunately, it didn't fix our problem.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot replicate this bug on iOS 8.1.2 Safari. The Mobile Safari bug that [**Aurélien** mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244897/152859) has possibly been corrected.

Comment: I can reproduce as well in iOS 8.1.2 Safari by clicking the sample link in the question to have it open within the app, then click the button on the bottom right, choose "Open in Safari" and then reload the page in Safari - it's OK initially, but upon reload I do get what the OP see.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I did the steps you outlined. I still can't repo.

Comment: Weird. Wonder if Aurélien can still reproduce? (in which case [tag:status-declined] might still be in order)