# No snowflake for full site on mobile

Tags: bug, winter-bash-2014, mobile-safari

The winter bash "snowflake" icon in the top nav is missing when the "full site" is rendered on my iPhone 5 using both chrome and safari. All Stack Exchange sites affected.

I'm looking at the same page simultaneously on desktop and mobile and the desktop has a little "2" in a light blue square to the left of the stack exchange drop down, but my mobile shows nothing there.

Having clicked the little "2" on desktop, the snowflake then appears instead. Still nothing on mobile.

A possible cause is that on the desktop, there are a couple of inches of space to the left of the drop down, but on mobile it is almost hard against the left edge - there may be more room for it to render there.

Comment: Weird, what happens when you navigate [directly to the image](http://cdn-prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash/img/topbar-snowflake.png?v=17e499f9cc96)?

Comment: @shadow I see the snowflake image OK when I open the link.

Comment: So it's clearly a design issue... did you try different browser, e.g. Chrome on the mobile device?

Comment: Worth to mention that mobile safari bugs [are not supported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244897/152859).

Comment: @shadow same problem on chrome too. I only tagged it mobile-safari cos there isn't a mobile-chrome tag

Comment: No repro for me, on iPhone 4S device, iOS 8 Safari browser. See the flake just fine. Maybe try clearing the cache?